# Sum of neighboring columns based on conditions

Tags: r, sum

I'm trying to sum up the values in exactly four neighboring columns starting with the column where I have the first value over zero. I.e. when the value in column x1 is 0 and the value in x2 is 1 then I want to have the sum of x2, x3, x4, x5. Let's assume the following example:

```
df<- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0), x2=c(0,3,0), x3=c(1,2,2), x4=c(3,4,4), x5=c(3,3,3), x6=c(3,4,5))

x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
1   0   1   3   3   3
0   3   2   4   3   4
0   0   2   4   3   5
```

In the first row the sum should start with the first value because this is the first value greater zero in the row. Then it should take the four consecutive columns, so x1+x2+x3+x4. In the second row the sum should start with the second value, so the sum would be x2+x3+x4+x5. In the third row the sum should start with x3, leading to x3+x4+x5+x6.

So what I want to get at the end is a column with the four consecutive sums:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  Sum
1   0   1   3   3   3    5
0   3   2   4   3   4    12
0   0   2   4   3   5    14
```

As I have nearly 40 columns and 300 rows I would really appreciate an elegant way to do it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following code

```
df$Sum <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(k) sum(df[k,head(which(df[k,]>0),1) + 0:3]))
```

which gives:

```
> df
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 Sum
1  1  0  1  3  3  3   5
2  0  3  2  4  3  4  12
3  0  0  2  4  3  5  14
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c(1, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 3, 0), x3 = c(1, 2,2), x4 = c(3, 4, 4), x5 = c(3, 3, 3), x6 = c(3, 4, 5)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked also with my original dataset. Can I select specific columns within your code? Because I do not want to consider all of my columns for the calculation (e.g. columns for names should be ignored). Or can I only solve this problem by building a subset selecting only the columns with numbers?

Comment: @ZayzayR Well, I think it's better to subset the columns you want to use, then apply the code on the selected columns. Otherwise, integrating the procedure of column selection will increase the  code complexity, and not straightforward for processing as well

Answer (score 0):

The `which` family of functions will identify the first nonzero.  There are various ways to loop: look to the `*apply` family.

Here's a tested solution.

```
f <- function(x) {
  i <- which.min(c(x,0)==0)
  sum(x[i+0:3], na.rm=TRUE)
}
#
# Test f.
#
stopifnot(mapply(function(x,y) f(x)==y,
       list(c(), 0, 1, c(1,NA), c(1,1), NA),
       c(0,0,1,1,2,0)))
#
# Do the calculation.
#
df<- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0), x2=c(0,3,0), x3=c(1,2,2), x4=c(3,4,4), x5=c(3,3,3), x6=c(3,4,5))
df$Sum <- apply(df, 1, f)

(df)
```

> ```
> x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 Sum
> 1  1  0  1  3  3  3   5
> 2  0  3  2  4  3  4  12
> 3  0  0  2  4  3  5  14
> ```

The core function `f` relies on two techniques worth noting:

1. It uses a "sentinel" 0 at the end of its argument to guarantee `which.min` returns a nonempty value.
2. It relies on `R` returning `NA` values for indexes beyond the valid range.  These are expressly ignored in the subsequent call to `sum`.

You will need to modify `f` if you want some kind of error or warning returned when there aren't at least four values in a row to sum.

Finally, the `stopifnot` unit test passes a list of test arguments to `f` (most of them "edge cases") and a list of the intended values for those cases.  It applies `f` to each of those arguments and compares its result to the intended value.  If there is any discrepancy, `R` will halt execution.  This helps assure you are getting the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `max.col` to find the column position of the first non zero value in each row, create the `row` and `column` index ('i', 'j') by making use of `rep`, extract the values in the dataset and get the `sum` grouped by the 'i' column

```
j <- max.col(df >0, 'first')
j <- j + rep(0:3, each = length(j))
i <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 4)
df$Sum <- tapply(df[cbind(i, j)], i, FUN = sum)
df
#  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 Sum
#1  1  0  1  3  3  3   5
#2  0  3  2  4  3  4  12
#3  0  0  2  4  3  5  14
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c(1, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 3, 0), x3 = c(1, 2, 
2), x4 = c(3, 4, 4), x5 = c(3, 3, 3), x6 = c(3, 4, 5)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```